# Razer Deathadder Elite: configure central buttons

Tags: 18.04, mouse, mouse-scroll, remapping

I need to use the two central buttons (the ones below the wheel) of the [Razer Deathadder Elite](https://www.razer.com/gaming-mice/razer-deathadder-elite) mouse to scroll pages.

[image: Razer Deathadder Mouse with two central buttons indicated with arrows]]

By default, they are used to change the DPI.

[OpenRazer](https://openrazer.github.io/) and [Polychromatic](https://polychromatic.app/) do not offer button remapping, if I am not wrong.

How can I simply and permanently reassign these two buttons to screen scrolling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RazerGenie](https://github.com/z3ntu/RazerGenie/blob/master/README.md)  does not have mouse button reassignment, nor is it on their [ToDo list](https://github.com/z3ntu/RazerGenie/issues). [razerCommander](https://gitlab.com/gabmus/razerCommander/blob/master/README.md) had [something close](https://gitlab.com/gabmus/razerCommander/issues/43), but it was generally problematic and [therefore dropped](https://github.com/openrazer/openrazer/commit/d1e683ac7cbaf0a70c6be1efc33d142f6c26ac72).

Therefore, I regret there is no simple and permanent reassignment of those two ('Sensitivity') buttons for Linux I could find.  You might look at their [support forums](https://insider.razer.com/index.php) to ask if any user there has a solution for you.